# IE9 divs with border-radius and bleeding background-colour and border

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

IE is showing a bleeding bg color and border on the header area [for example here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html) in IE9.  The CSS is below, but I can't understand why..

```
#header-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 98.2%;
    margin: 0 0.8%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #333441;
    border-bottom: 0;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f6f6f6), to(#E4E4E4));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f6f6f6,  #e4e4e4);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f6f6f6', endColorstr='#e4e4e4');
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
}
```

Any ideas would be great..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

http://abouthalf.com/2010/10/25/internet-explorer-9-gradients-with-rounded-corners/

Comment: Use http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ - select ie9 support - it gives you svg code for ie9. Add filter: none; to the div in ie9 stylesheet

Comment: Hi uname12, would you like to share your solution with us?

Answer (score 0):

If available within your project constraints. I would suggest using something like [bourbon](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon), which gives you all the mixins to do what you need, with browser compatibility in mind. However, such a tool requires SASS. Which in the long run, isn't a bad idea to know / have.

Alternatively there are other tools like [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), that can help you in this case as well.

Moreover, you can dig into the source code CSS frameworks such as [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons) and grab the code they are using for border radius.